# Nginx reverse proxy for a React app gives "502 Bad Gateway"

Tags: reactjs, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am attempting to deploy a website built with ReactJS on a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Compute Engine virtual machine (VM). My plan is to copy the front-end build files and the back-end files to the VM and then run them on two ports using npm `serve` package, then using nginx reverse proxy redirect the requests to that ports.

These are the steps I followed.

1. Added the following lines to my `package.json` file (I have my back-end on port 5000)

   ```json
   "proxy": "http://34.125.6.215:5000",
   "homepage": "http://34.125.6.215/test"
   ```
2. Built the React app and copied the build files into the VM.
3. Installed the `serve` npm package and served the build files on port 4000 using the command:

   ```bash
   serve -l 4000 -s build
   ```
4. To set up a reverse proxy, I created a `web-app.conf` file inside the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` directory with the following content:

   ```
   server {
       listen 80;
       server_name 34.125.6.215;

       location /test/ {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:4000; 
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
           proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
           proxy_redirect off;
       }
   }
   ```

However, when I try to access the `34.125.6.215/test` endpoint from my browser, I encounter a 502 Bad Gateway error. What could be the cause of this error? What might I be doing wrong in my setup?